# Tikz Pie Charts

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgf-pie

Is there a way to make a pie chart with Tikz so that the labels are not numbers (e.g. 30/70 in my example) but the labels are displayed as variables (e.g. omega and 1- omega)?

Here is what I currently have:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \pie{30/Stock, 70/Bond}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

I do not want it to say 30/70, and want to be able to label it with a Greek letter instead.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). Please try to do something by yourself and then add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) to your post. Without showing any of your effort to draw this diagram, your question is "do-it-for-me" which is unlikely to be answered.

Comment: I did put in my code. Do you see it?

Comment: You can easily modify the code [here](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/pie-chart/).

Comment: Alan could you give a bit more explanation - that diagram has percentages showing up too. How would that be adjusted to get what I'm looking for?

Comment: He might not have seen your comment. You as the owner of the post is notified of all comments, other commenters are not notified unless you write an at-sign followed by the username, e.g. @Alan. That said, try replacing `{\p\%}{\t}` with `{\t}{}`.

Comment: The are two ways to go here: One can modify \pie to make it do what you want, or you can just draw everything using arcs and lines.  I would choose the latter.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. That was extremely helpful -- one last question, is there an easy way to have a different color for the two regions? I can't seem to figure that piece out. I used your comment and the labels look great, but the \draw[thick,fill=black!10] part of the code I can't figure out how to split the color for the two regions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer your original question, I don't know if there is any built-in method in `pgf-pie` to have only textual labels and not the numbers, but it is possible to patch the macro responsible for making a slice to achieve that:

[image: output of first code with pgf-pie]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgf-pie}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\pgfpie@slice}% this is the macro we're patching
{\scalefont{#3}\shortstack{#4\\\beforenumber#3\afternumber}}% find this
{\scalefont{#3}#4}% and replace with this
{}{}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \pie[text=inside]{30/$\omega$, 70/$1-\omega$}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

If you want to use the code from the example Alan mentioned, you'll need to modify it to use a third loop variable, for defining the colour. I indicated in the code where I made modifications.

[image: output of code]

```
% Original code from http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/pie-chart/
% by Robert Vollmert
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\newcommand{\slice}[5]{% changed 4 to 5, fifth argument to define colour
  \pgfmathparse{0.5*#1+0.5*#2}
  \let\midangle\pgfmathresult

  % slice
  % add #5 after fill=
  \draw[thick,fill=#5] (0,0) -- (#1:1) arc (#1:#2:1) -- cycle;

  % outer label
  \node[label=\midangle:#4] at (\midangle:1) {};

  % inner label
  \pgfmathparse{min((#2-#1-10)/110*(-0.3),0)}
  \let\temp\pgfmathresult
  \pgfmathparse{max(\temp,-0.5) + 0.8}
  \let\innerpos\pgfmathresult
  \node at (\midangle:\innerpos) {#3};
}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=3]

\newcounter{a}
\newcounter{b}
% add third loop variable for colour
\foreach \p/\t/\clr in {30/$\omega$/blue!20, 70/$1-\omega$/red!30}
  {
    \setcounter{a}{\value{b}}
    \addtocounter{b}{\p}
    \slice{\thea/100*360}
          {\theb/100*360}
          {\t}{}{\clr} % added fifth argument, {\clr}
  }

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Finally, for a simple two-part pie here is one way of doing it from scratch.

[image: output of code]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\filldraw[draw=black,fill=blue!30] (0,0) -- (0:2cm) arc[start angle=0,end angle=120,radius=2cm] -- cycle;
\filldraw[draw=black,fill=red!30] (0,0) -- (120:2cm) arc[start angle=120,end angle=360,radius=2cm] -- cycle;
\node at (60:1cm) {$\omega$};
\node at (240:1cm) {$1-\omega$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Perfect! This got the job done, and then I added in two nodes for the stock/bond labes: \node at (240:2.5cm) {Bond};
\node at (60:2.5cm) {Stock};

Comment: @ZakFischer If the answer worked for you, please consider accepting it by clicking on the check mark left of it.

Comment: @marmot Got it - done!

Answer (score 2):

Nowadays (v0.7), pgf-pie has an `hide number` option that seems to do exactly that.

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgf-pie}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \pie[text=inside, hide number]{30/$\omega$, 70/$1-\omega$}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

With the [recent](https://www.ctan.org/ctan-ann/id/mailman.525.1663101608.3715.ctan-ann@ctan.org) [`wheelchart`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/wheelchart) package:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{wheelchart}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\wheelchart[pie, wheel data={\WCvarC}, wheel data pos=0.5, data={}]
     {30/{blue!30}/$w$,70/{blue!50}/$1-w$}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]